# how to print the 4th iterations in selection sort in java and the the solution for the below test cases

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort

Sort the given set of numbers using Selection Sort.

The first line of the input contains the number of elements, the second line of the input contains the numbers to be sorted. In the output print the status of the array at the 4th iteration and the final sorted array in the given format

```
Logic Test Case 1

Input (stdin)
5

25 47 11 65 1

Expected Output

1 11 25 65 47 

Sorted Array:

1 11 25 47 65
Logic Test Case 2

Input (stdin)
7

14 83 25 47 9 77 1

Expected Output

1 9 14 47 83 77 25 

Sorted Array:

1 9 14 25 47 77 83
```

kindly try to solve this problem in java.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works as you expect in the question.

> PS - Make sure u try something on your own instead of directly asking
>   a question.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SelectionSort {

private static void sort(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int minIdx = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[j] < arr[minIdx])
                minIdx = j;

        // Swap number to correct position
        int temp = arr[minIdx];
        arr[minIdx] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        if (i == 2) { // 0 based index, 2 - is the fourth iteration [n-1]
            print(arr);
        }
    }
}

private static void print(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(value -> System.out.print(value + " "));
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Test 1
    int[] arr1 = new int[]{25, 47, 11, 65, 1};
    sort(arr1);
    print(arr1);


    // Test 2
    int[] arr2 = new int[]{14, 83, 25, 47, 9, 77, 1};
    sort(arr2);
    print(arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask you why do you need to print the 4th iteration?
But on the other hand you can implement a selection sort algorithm and count the iterations in the loop, when it comes to four you can print it and continue the whole loop until it sorts the full number set.

```
public class SelectionSort {

  public SelectionSort() {

  }

  int [] a={1 ,11 ,25 ,65 ,47 };

  public void getSorted(){

  for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){

    if(i==3) {

      for (int o = 0; o < a.length; o++)
        System.out.printf("%d ",a[o]);

      System.out.println();

    }

    int min=i;
    boolean depend=false;

    for(int j=i;j<a.length-1;j++){

      if(a[min] > a[j+1]) {

        min = j + 1;
        depend=true;

      }

    }

    if(depend==true)
      this.swap(i,min);

  }

    System.out.println("Sorted array :");

  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    System.out.printf("%d ",a[i]);

  }

  private void swap(int i, int min){

    int temp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[min];
    a[min]=temp;

  }

}
```

In this particular selection sort algorithm when you want print the 4th iteration it prints the array when `i==3` returns `true`. We expect `i` to be `3`at the 4th iteration because we index an array from `0`.